# Gtk - call a function with variable period

Tags: gtk, ocaml

I am coding with gtk and ocaml, and I'm completely new working with them. I know that you can call a function periodically in gtk with `g_timeout_add`. But I want to change the period of the function being called based on another event. Is there a way to do that?

I wrote a function that based on an event, would call the `g_timeout_add` again with the new period but it doesn't seem working OK. I'm not sure but it seems that I can increase the period but can't decrease it.

**Edit**

Here is a simple pseudo code of what I'm doing:

```
let tag = Glib.timeout.add period (fun () -> myfunc x; true;) in
let loop = Glib.Main.create true in
while Glib.Main.is_running loop do ignore (Glib.Main.iteration true) done
```

And in `myfunc` I'm doing sth like this:

```
let rec myfunc =fun x
    if x = "sth coming from somewhere else" then
        ignore (Glib.timeout.add new_period (fun () -> myfunc x; true;))
```

Comment: You can't change the timeout of an existing source but replacing it with a new one has the same result. Add a minimal  example that shows the problem so someone can point out what's going wrong.

Comment: @jku  I added a simple code to my post

Answer (score 0):

You are adding a anonymous function at the start. Then later, in myfunc, you again add a (different) anonymous function. How is Glib supposed to know that you want to replace the original function? For anonymous functions you have to explicitly remove the old function.

Reading the glib API you have two choices:

1. Call `void g_source_remove (gint tag)` to remove the old function.
2. You may also stop the timeout function by returning zero or FALSE from your callback function.

Check if either of those two are present in the ocaml bindings.